# Delete all text in a variable before a certain word in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I'm trying to isolate a certain phrase in a variable.

I know I can do the below to get rid of everything after the word but not sure how to do it for everything before the word:

```
$Trimthis -replace '(?<=elephant)(.\n|.)*'
```

Comment: Try : $s = '(?<=elephant)(.\n|.)*';
$index = $s.Indexof('elephant')
$t = $s.Substring($index)

Answer (score 1):

As Santiago suggests, you can use a (positive) **look-*ahead* assertion** (`(?=…)`):

```bash
@'
No, there is
no elephant
in the room.
'@ -replace '(?s)^.*(?=elephant.*$)'
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/fhaR8L/1)
Note that `(?s)` is the inline form of the `SingleLine` .NET regex option, which makes `.` match  newlines (`\n`) too.

---

Alternatively, use a **capture group** (`(…)`) to capture the part that must be preserved, which you can reference as `$1` in the substitution operand of the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```bash
@'
No, there is
no elephant
in the room.
'@ -replace '(?s)^.*(elephant.*$)', '$1'
```

See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/m6nQWj/1).

---

Output:

```bash
elephant
in the room.
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the text before the first occurrence of elephant, you can use the lookahead with a non greedy quantifier and having the dot match a newline with  for example in inline modifier `(?s)`

```
$Trimthis -replace '(?s)^.*?(?=elephant)'
```